# In my Terraria save files the world and player files are empty - where would my PLR file be?

Tags: terraria, mods

Trying to install [Terrasavr](http://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/) but I cant find the PLR file in the folder. Where would these be?

Answer (score 2):

These files should be stored in `%userprofile%\My Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players` (`%userprofile%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players` on Windows 8/8.1/10).

Comment: ive looked in those folders but its empty

Comment: Have you checked to make sure they are not hidden? Also make sure you can load your character, if you can't it might be missing.

Comment: How would they be hidden? And if so how can I undo it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved your players and worlds the the cloud they are moved from you "my games" folder. Steam moves them to the "userdata" folder inside the steam directory. Inside the "userdata" folder there will be numbered folders for each person who uses your computer if its only you there will only be one folder. Inside your folder there will be numbered game folders, Terraria is number 105600. Inside you will find the "remote" folder that holds all your saves.